# HTML choose three different checkbox and show them

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a very simple HTML page with different checkboxes and I wish to select three of them and show the name of the product below.

What I need, for example if I choose the checkboxes nº 1, 3 and 4, I need to see:

Choose 3 perfumes

1. Eau d'Issey
2. Tropical
3. Eau d'Issey2

But everytime I click in one checkbox I get three identical results. Can anyone help me with that?
My code is below...

Thank you very much!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function exefunction(me) {
      var check = document.getElementById(me.id).checked;
      var checked_value;
      var str1 = "product";
      var n = 1;
      for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        if (check) {
          checked_value = document.getElementById(me.id).name
          document.getElementById("product" + n).innerHTML = checked_value;
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>1.
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Eau d'Issey" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
    <p>2.
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Fahrenheit" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
      <p>3.
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Tropical" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
        <p>4.
          <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Eau d'Issey2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
          <p>5.
            <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Fahrenheit2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
            <p>6.
              <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Tropical2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">

              <p>Choose 3 perfumes.</p>
              <h3>1: </h3>
              <p id="product1"></p>
              <h3>2: </h3>
              <p id="product2"></p>
              <h3>3: </h3>
              <p id="product3"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please use the tidy button in the snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use numbers for id value, id="1" will maybe work somewhere but id attributes must start with letter. Close your html tags which need to be closed. in this example it won't affect how program works but a lot of times it will. A lot of javascript bugs are caused by bad html.
In your program you already have html object, you don't need to search for its id attribute, instead of:

```
 document.getElementById(me.id).checked;
```

You can use

```
me.checked
```

This example is maybe not exactly what you want but it's improvement.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var n=1;
            function exefunction(me) {
                var checked_value=me.getAttribute('name');
                if(me.checked){
                    document.getElementById("product" + n).innerHTML = checked_value;
                    n++;
                    if(n==4)n=1;
                }else{
                    for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
                        var d=document.getElementById('product'+i);
                        if(d.innerHTML==checked_value && d.innerHTML!=''){
                            d.innerHTML="";
                            n=i;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    <p>1. <input type="checkbox" name="Eau d'Issey" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    <p>2. <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrenheit" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    <p>3. <input type="checkbox" name="Tropical" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    <p>4. <input type="checkbox" name="Eau d'Issey2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    <p>5. <input type="checkbox" name="Fahrenheit2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    <p>6. <input type="checkbox" name="Tropical2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);"></p>
    
    <p>Choose 3 perfumes.</p>
    <h3>1: </h3>
    <p id="product1"></p>
    <h3>2: </h3>
    <p id="product2"></p>
    <h3>3: </h3>
    <p id="product3"></p>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Sir, you saved my day. Thank you very much for your brightness!

Comment: There is an issue when you try to uncheck the 3rd checkbox. I tried to figure out how to solve it but I cannot with it yet. Can you help me? Thanks very much.

Comment: because I put <3 instead of <=3 ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Final code

```
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function exefunction(me) {
      var check = document.getElementById(me.id).checked;
      var checked_value;
      var str1 = "product";
      checked_value = document.getElementById(me.id).name
      for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
          if(document.getElementById("product" + (i+1)).innerHTML === ""){
               document.getElementById("product" + (i+1)).innerHTML = checked_value;
               return;}
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>1.
    <input type="checkbox" id="1" name="Eau d'Issey" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
    <p>2.
      <input type="checkbox" id="2" name="Fahrenheit" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
      <p>3.
        <input type="checkbox" id="3" name="Tropical" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
        <p>4.
          <input type="checkbox" id="4" name="Eau d'Issey2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
          <p>5.
            <input type="checkbox" id="5" name="Fahrenheit2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">
            <p>6.
              <input type="checkbox" id="6" name="Tropical2" title="Select All" onclick="exefunction(this);">

              <p>Choose 3 perfumes.</p>
              <h3>1: </h3>
              <p id="product1"></p>
              <h3>2: </h3>
              <p id="product2"></p>
              <h3>3: </h3>
              <p id="product3"></p>

</body>

</html>
```